# Proving equilateral triangle

Tags: analytic-geometry

Show that the lines $x^2+16xy-11y^2=0$ form an equilateral triangle with the line $2x+y+1=0$ and find its area.

--------________________________---------

My solution is here;
Here $x^2+16xy-11y^2=0$ represents a pair of straight lines.
Comparing with $ax^2+bx+c=0$ and using the quadratic formula i.e. $x={-b+/-√(b^2-4ac)}/2a$ I got $x=-8y+/-5y√3$.
Now, how do i move ahead

Comment: find their intersection points find distance between them if all distances are same then triangle is equilateral and area=$1/2a b sinC$

Comment: @Archis how should I do that?  Could you give any more hints.

Comment: Do you not know how to find the point of intersection of two lines?  one line is given by x= -8+ 5y sqrt(3) and another by x= -8- 5y sqrt(3).  Adding two equations, 2x= -16.   The third line is 2x+ y+ 1= 0,  x= -1/2- y/2.  That intersects x= -8+ 5y sqrt(3) where -1/2- y/2= -8+ 5y sqrt(3).

Comment: @usee247327, Ok Let me try with it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pair of lines intersect at the origin, so let each line be $y=mx$. Substitute for $y$: 
$$x^2+16mx^2-11m^2x^2=0$$

This gives the quadratic equation, satisfied by both gradients:

$$11m^2-16m-1=0\Rightarrow m=\frac{8\pm5\sqrt{3}}{11}$$

Now consider the line through the origin which is perpendicular to the third side $2x+y+1=0$ which is $$2y=x$$

We can rotate this line by $\pm 30^o$ by using the rotation matrix $$Rot(\alpha)=\left(\begin{matrix}\cos \alpha &-\sin \alpha \\ \sin\alpha& \cos\alpha\end{matrix}\right)$$

This leads to two lines, passing through the origin, whose gradients are exactly as before, $\frac{8\pm5\sqrt{3}}{11}$.

This confirms that the triangle formed by these lines is equilateral.

To calculate the area, you just need the height of the triangle, which is the perpendicular distance from the origin to the line $2x+y+1$, namely $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$ then the area of the triangle is $$\frac 15 \tan 30$$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: could you explain me how did you get $11m^2-16m-1=0$

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: @ David, Ok i understood this and could you please explain me about the rotation matrix. i am not familiar with this as I haven't read about it till now.

Comment: there's lots on the web about rotation matrices such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix. it's possible to do it without matrices also...

Comment: How should I do it without using matrices..

Comment: show that the angle between each of the lines of the line pair and the line $2y=x$ is $30^o$, using the formula for the angle between two lines of given gradient

Comment: Ok, let me try//